# vuetify main left position updated to zero

Tags: vuetify.js

i have some issue with v-app-bar and v-navigation-drawer. I copy all code from exemple by Vuetify.
First load, all elements are placed correctly.

But, when I click on icon in navigation-drawer, v-main left position always upated to 0px.

[image]

as you can see in the picture, the v-main is behind the v-navigation-drawer due to the left position to 0px. when I click on the refresh button, the position is correct.

how can i fix this issue ?

here are some code:

[image]

[image]

i can send a zip code, but it seems not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, I just overwrite css vuetifiy component.

```
.v-main {
    position:absolute !important;
    display:block !important;
    left: 60px !important;
    top: 80px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.v-app-bar {
    left:55px !important;
}
```

hope can help

Comment: Ovewritting css lib classes is a bad practice. You shoul create new classes that you will add to your components doing the same as you wrote ahead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).